# laravel read ical file and parse value to a database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have ical file locally and I am retrieving it and converting to an array like this:

```
    $ical = new ICal('ical/basic.ics');
    $test = ($ical->events());
    dd($test);
```

Which gives me an output like:

[ICAL 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqZ08.jpg)

And each item in an array has values such as:

[ICAL example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EViG.jpg)

What I want to do is write a loop that would loop throught each array and output for example 'summary' then I will expand it to do what I want it to do however the question is how to write such a loop?

Comment: Uhm... `foreach ($ical->events() as $event) { echo $event->summary; }`? Just like every foreach loop ever?

Comment: Which package did you used to read iCal link/file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the event with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($ical->events() as $event) {
    var_dump($event->summary);
}
```